# Apache2 Enabling Server Side Includes breaks Basic Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using Apache 2.2.12 on Ubuntu 9.10. When I enable the "include" module (for Server Side Includes), basic authentication to other areas of my site quit working. Instead of showing a prompt in the browser for the user/pass, apache just redirects to /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var. Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?